# How do I set my label's text with a value from the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I got in my database a column "Klantnummer" and
 I want that value as my label text.
How do I do that?

```
protected string conS = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Databees.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
protected SqlConnection con;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(conS);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        string q = "SELECT * FROM tblKLanten;";
        SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(q, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = query.ExecuteReader();
        Label1.Text = ; //I want here the value of klantnummer
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label2.Text = "Error";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
label1.Text = dr["Klantnummes"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, with the information provided it's not terribly easy to answer, but let's ***assume*** your structure is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tblKLanten (
    ID INT,
    Klantnummer VARCHAR(50)
)
```

you'll need to get the field by the index from the reader like this:

```
Label1.Text = dr.GetString(1);
```

but you're also going to need to read, so you'll need to issue this statement before setting the label:

```
bool success = dr.Read();
if (success)
{
    // set the label in here
}
```

but remember, it's based off of the ***index of the column in the returned statement*** and so since you're issuing a `SELECT *` there's no way for me to know what the index is. In the end, I would recommend making some more changes, so consider the following code:

```
protected string conS = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Databees.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
protected SqlConnection con;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(conS);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        string q = "SELECT * FROM tblKLanten;";
        SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(q, con);

        using (SqlDataReader dr = query.ExecuteReader())
        {
            bool success = dr.Read();
            if (success)
            {
                Label1.Text = dr.GetString(1);
            }
        }

        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label2.Text = "Error";
    }
}
```

the `using` statement there will make sure that the `SqlDataReader` gets disposed properly.